# C++ Preprocessor directives as a function parameter

Tags: c++, preprocessor-directive

I started learning C++ using a ebook and got interupted by a few lines, which I think are a bit outdated. Anyway, what I am trying to do is using a preprocessor directive as a function parameter which isnt working:

```
#define TitleLabelId 1000;

//....

hTitleText = CreateWindow(L"STATIC",
                          L"Test Text",
                          WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD,
                          0, 0,
                          300, 20,
                          hWnd,
                          (HMENU)TitleLabelId,
                          hInst,
                          NULL);
```

This gives me an compile error, while this will give me a correct result:

```
HMENU hm = (HMENU)TitleLabelId;

hTitleText = CreateWindow(L"STATIC",
                          L"Test Text",
                          WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD,
                          0, 0,
                          300, 20,
                          hWnd,
                          (HMENU)TitleLabelId,
                          hInst,
                          NULL);
```

I tried to outsource the Label Text aswell but unfortunateley it didnt work either using the following directive:

```
#define TitleText L"Blob Color War";
```

Is it anything with the syntax I have overseen? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have to remember that the preprocessor is not the compiler, its directives are terminated by the end of the line and not be a specific terminator character (like the C++ language). Also, macros are replaced verbatim with the macro bodies.

Comment: In the future when you're having problem with the preprocessor, you might want to generate pre-processed files, which is the output of the preprocessor and the input to the "proper" compiler. Looking through this can often help you figure out preprocessor problems.

Comment: I will try to find out, how to do that in VS2013

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `#define` without the semicolon afterwards:

```
#define TitleLabelId 1000;
                      // ^

#define TitleLabelId 1000
```

Otherwise it will be expanded during prprocessing, but is wrong inside the parameter list.

Answer (score 4):

```
#define TitleText L"Blob Color War";
```

I think the `;` is creating some issues. Removing that would fix it.

```
#define TitleText L"Blob Color War"
```